# Need to sort section header title by date

Tags: ios, uitableview, nsdate

Each section header in my UITableView is a date. I can set up the headers just fine, however, the headers are sorted alphabetically, instead of by date. So, Monday is above Saturday, and Saturday is above Wednesday. Is there any way to sort the headers by date, chronologically?

Here is the code I'm using to setup the section headers where `entry.sectionName` (type = string) is an attribute in my model entity, and also serves as my sectionNameKeyPath.

```
//set sectionName
NSDate *headerDate = [NSDate date];
NSDateFormatter *headerDateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[headerDateFormatter setDateFormat:@"EEEE MMMM d, yyyy"];
NSString *headerDateString = [headerDateFormatter stringFromDate:headerDate];
entry.sectionName = headerDateString;
```

I assume the sectionName attribute needs to be a Date instead of a String? Is this correct and if so, what does the code look like for this? I'm using the code below to change it back to a NSDate, but it doesn't seem to work or display any data.

```
//set sectionName
NSDate *headerDate = [NSDate date];
NSDateFormatter *headerDateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[headerDateFormatter setDateFormat:@"EEEE MMMM d, yyyy"];
NSString *headerDateString = [headerDateFormatter stringFromDate:headerDate];

NSDateFormatter *inFormat = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[inFormat setDateFormat:@"MMM dd, yyyy"];

NSDate *parsed = [inFormat dateFromString:headerDateString];

entry.sectionName = parsed;
```

Below is the Fetched Results Controller

```
-(NSFetchRequest *)entryListFetchRequest{
NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [NSFetchRequest fetchRequestWithEntityName:@"BreastEntry"];
[fetchRequest setSortDescriptors:@[[NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"sectionName" ascending:YES],
                                   [NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"timePicker" ascending:NO]]];


return fetchRequest;
}



-(NSFetchedResultsController *)fetchedResultsController{
if(_fetchedResultsController != nil){
    return _fetchedResultsController;
}

CoreDataStack *coreDataStack =[CoreDataStack defaultStack];
NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [self entryListFetchRequest];

_fetchedResultsController = [[NSFetchedResultsController alloc] initWithFetchRequest:fetchRequest managedObjectContext:coreDataStack.managedObjectContext sectionNameKeyPath:@"sectionName" cacheName:nil];
_fetchedResultsController.delegate = self;

return _fetchedResultsController;

}
```

titleForSectionInHeader method

```
-(NSString*)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView titleForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section{

id<NSFetchedResultsSectionInfo> sectionInfo = [self.fetchedResultsController sections][section];
return [sectionInfo name];
```

}

Comment: Normally your data should be in the correct order before using them inside UITableView. Could you please add the code where you sort your "entry" objects?

Comment: @AlexVogel see updated question with FRC

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand your code correctly you are creating the section names before saving them to CoreData. You are creating the section names in the format `"EEEE MMMM d, yyyy"` which has the name of the day as first item. Sorting this data truly gives you a sorting where Monday comes before Saturday (M << S), because it will sort alphabetically. Try to store your date information in another which can easily sorted only by direct date information (like `"yyyy-MM-dd"`). So the code sorts the date with year first, month second and day as third parameter.

While creating the text for the headers inside UITableView you can now format the date information in every other way you wish  (using `NSDateFormatter` to create a NSDate object first and than your requested text format).

*Note: This is a "I'm not 100 % sure it will work" answer, but the way I would do that.*

Comment: This sounds like a logical/reasonable approach. I understand the first part, I think. So are you suggesting my sectionName(attribute) should be in the form of an NSString or an NSDate? As far as your second paragraph, are you suggesting formatting the date in the titleForHeaderInSectionMethod? If so, what would something look like for this?  (I have added my titleForHeaderInSectionMethod above, updated code)